# Indiana Jones has been shot nine times. Can you account for all nine?

Tags: indiana-jones, indiana-jones-the-dial-of-destiny

In the recent movie ''Indiana Jones and the Dial of Destiny'', when Indiana Jones and Helena climb up a wall in the cave of Dionysos, Indiana complains that he can't climb so easily because he's old, he has screws and plates in his legs, was forced to drink the blood of Kali, and **has been shot nine times**.

Can you list all nine times that Indiana Jones has been shot?  I'd like to get answers based on the films and supplementary material.

Comment: 10 or more times, depending on what sources you use. Several more if you include *Young Indiana Jones* and a dozen more times if you include all the novels;  https://screenrant.com/indiana-jones-movies-character-shot/

Comment: I wonder if his elbow still doesn’t hurt